# Length in serde serialize

Tags: rust, serde

Maybe I haven't read the documentation too carefully but, I didn't manage to get answer to the following question.

When having a custom serialization logic defined like:

```rs
pub fn serialize_foo<S>(t: &Foo, serializer: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error>
where
    S: Serializer,
{
    let mut map = serializer.serialize_map(Some(len))?;
    /*
    ...
    */
    map.end()
}
```

What is `len`? Is it the size of a type defined in bytes, or is it something else? For example, what would be the type for `i32` in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [`Serializer::serialize_map`](https://docs.rs/serde/latest/serde/trait.Serializer.html#tymethod.serialize_map):

> **The argument is the number of elements in the map**, which may or may not be computable before the map is iterated. Some serializers only support maps whose length is known up front.

So it is the number of times that you will call `.serialize_entry()` (or `.serialize_key()` and `.serialize_value()` pairs) on `map`.

Comment: Oh, this makes sense, I was thinking in a totally different direction :P